# How to delete all but two instances of a file?

Tags: bash

I have a directory with similarly named files, in this pattern:

```
00002_930831_fa.ppm  00398_940422_fa.ppm  00714_960530_fa.ppm
00002_930831_fb.ppm  00398_940422_fb.ppm  00714_960530_fb.ppm
00002_931230_fa.ppm  00399_940422_fa.ppm  00714_960620_fa.ppm
00002_931230_fb.ppm  00399_940422_fb.ppm  00714_960620_fb.ppm
00002_940128_fa.ppm  00400_940422_fa.ppm  00715_941201_fa.ppm
00002_940128_fb.ppm  00400_940422_fb.ppm  00715_941201_fb.ppm
00002_940422_fa.ppm  00401_940422_fa.ppm  00715_941205_fa.ppm
00002_940422_fb.ppm  00401_940422_fb.ppm  00715_941205_fb.ppm
00002_940928_fa.ppm  00402_940422_fa.ppm  00716_941201_fa.ppm
00002_940928_fb.ppm  00402_940422_fb.ppm  00716_941201_fb.ppm
```

What I need to do is remove for example all but two instances of the 00002 sample (doesn't matter which ones), so that I'm left for example with `00002_930831_fa.ppm` and `00002_930831_fb.ppm`. The problem is I need this done for all samples, 00003, 00004 and so on. I need to be left with two files for each sample.

I've tried with `find` but I'm not sure how to frase my condition.

Can this be solved by simply piping commands or do I have to solve it with a bash script?

Comment: rm $(ls 00002_* | tail -n +3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ BASH_VERSINFO -ge 4 ]] || {
    echo "You need Bash 4.0 or newer to run this script." >&2
    exit 1
}

declare -A COUNTER=()

for A in *.ppm; do
    IFS=_ read I __ <<< "$A"
    (( ++COUNTER[$I] > 2 )) && rm "$A" 
done
```

Simulation:

```
Skip 00002_930831_fa.ppm
Skip 00002_930831_fb.ppm
rm 00002_931230_fa.ppm
rm 00002_931230_fb.ppm
rm 00002_940128_fa.ppm
rm 00002_940128_fb.ppm
rm 00002_940422_fa.ppm
rm 00002_940422_fb.ppm
rm 00002_940928_fa.ppm
rm 00002_940928_fb.ppm
Skip 00398_940422_fa.ppm
Skip 00398_940422_fb.ppm
Skip 00399_940422_fa.ppm
Skip 00399_940422_fb.ppm
Skip 00400_940422_fa.ppm
Skip 00400_940422_fb.ppm
Skip 00401_940422_fa.ppm
Skip 00401_940422_fb.ppm
Skip 00402_940422_fa.ppm
Skip 00402_940422_fb.ppm
Skip 00714_960530_fa.ppm
Skip 00714_960530_fb.ppm
rm 00714_960620_fa.ppm
rm 00714_960620_fb.ppm
Skip 00715_941201_fa.ppm
Skip 00715_941201_fb.ppm
rm 00715_941205_fa.ppm
rm 00715_941205_fb.ppm
Skip 00716_941201_fa.ppm
Skip 00716_941201_fb.ppm
```

Note: Test it first on some dummy files.

Come to think of it:

```
IFS=_ read I __ <<< "$A"
```

Can just be

```
I=${A%%_*}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `head` or `tail` to filter your filename list:

```
ls 00002_* | tail -n +3 | xargs rm
```

Comment: You might want to add a grep in there for 00002. He's only looking for files from the 00002 sample. So: `ls | grep 00002 | tail -n +3 | xargs rm`

Comment: OP wanted the 00002 files, so ls 00002_* and then everything else, I think.

Comment: Sorry -- I was answering while you answered.

Comment: this would be great but unfortunately I didn't frase my question correctly before posting... I edited it now

Comment: First, get a list of the patterns:  "ls | cut -c0-5 | sort -u"
Then do what was said above: "ls {patterns found above} | tail -n +3 | xargs rm"

Answer (score 2):

Create an array that contains all matching file names, then use the substring parameter expansion operator to pass all but the first two elements as arguments to `rm`.

```
while read -r sample; do
  matching_files=( ${sample}_* )
  # To make sure at least two files survive:
  (( ${#matching_files[@]} > 2 )) && rm "${matching_files[@]:2}"
done < samples.txt
```

Comment: this works well, thank you! the only problem is that some samples have only two files and using your code I would delete them as well... I'm afraid I'll have to use a counter of some sort

Answer (score 0):

with bash version 4:

```
declare -A files
for f in *ppm; do
    files[${f%%_*}]+="$f "
done
for i in "${!files[@]}"; do
    set -- ${files[$i]}
    shift 2
    (($# > 0)) && echo rm $*
done
```

Remove `echo` if you're satisfied it's selecting the right files to delete.

Won't work if there are any filenames with whitespace.